# Flutter not displaying images according to official docs

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-appbar

I'm following a popular flutter tutorial and I seem to be the only person having this problem, which has also baffled the instructor.

***The problem:*** Images do not display according to official documents.

***The workaround solution:*** Add a trailing './' to the widget referencing the file.

***Question:*** Why is this happening?

***pubspec.yaml code:***

```
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true

  assets:
    - assets/food.jpg
```

***code without trailing './'***

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('EasyList'),
        ),
        body: Card(child: Column(children: <Widget>[
          Image.asset('assets/food.jpg'),
          Text('Food Paradise')
        ],),),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

***code with trailing './'***

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('EasyList'),
        ),
        body: Card(child: Column(children: <Widget>[
          Image.asset('./assets/food.jpg'),
          Text('Food Paradise')
        ],),),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you use the Packages Get? command, `flutter packages get`

Comment: Hi Juan. I just tried that but it didn't resolve the issue.

Comment: the path is relative to pubspec.yaml as given in https://flutter.io/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images#asset-bundling and the actual directory does not matter. Looks like your path is incorrect or something. Answer given by @JuanEstebanLondoñoTabares works fine.

Comment: I'm assuming you are right that my path is incorrect somehow, somewhere. But I read through the assets and images docs and I can't seem to uncover the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Look I just created a project with the code you indicated above, and it works correctly without `` / `, then I share the code you use and the structure of the project.

**file main.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('EasyList'),
        ),
        body: Card(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Image.asset('assets/food.jpg'),
              Text('Food Paradise')
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**file pubspec.yaml**
    name: prueba
    description: A new Flutter project.

```
# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# Read more about versioning at semver.org.
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.0.0-dev.68.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter


# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - assets/food.jpg
```

**this is the structure of the project**

[image]

**and the result is the following:**

[image]

your code you share looks good, if everything is well configured it should work without problems.

Comment: Thank you Juan. I have precisely the exact same setup and my pubspec.yaml file is identical to yours. Yet my code only works with a trailing './' in the main.dart file